# I'm trying to implement passport-local but i'm getting error

Tags: node.js, passport.js

This is the error I'm getting in `passport.js` config. I don't understand what it means: Why `passport.use` is not a function?

```
TypeError: passport.use is not a function
```

This is my code:

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// load user models 
const User = require('../models/Users');

module.exports =  function (passport) {
  passport.use (
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
      // Match User
      User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' })
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })

      // match password
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) throw (err)

        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user)
        } else {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect Password' })
        }
      })
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser( (id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user)  => {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport")
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('./models/user');



// Local Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
        // find the user given the email
        const user = await User.findOne({ "email": email });

        // if not, handle it
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        // check if password is correct
        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);

        // if not handle it
        if (!isMatch) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        // otherwise return the user
        done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
        done(error, false);
    }
}));
```

Comment: there is no serializer and deserializer?